# Why using inner join itself is more faster than where

Tags: mysql, indexing

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cerp_oms_order` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `company_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `order_no` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `source_type` int NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `outer_shop` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `origin_status` int NOT NULL,
  `system_status` int NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modify_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_deadline_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
  `spu_kind` int NOT NULL,
  `sku_kind` int NOT NULL,
  `total_quantity` decimal(16,4) NOT NULL,
  `buyer_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `outer_buyer_identifier` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tax_info` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `warehouse_owner` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `logistics_type` int NOT NULL,
  `logistics_outer_info` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_no` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `wave_no` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
  `is_deleted` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `backend_processing_type` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `create_type` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `is_hang_up` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `hang_up_case_type` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `hang_up_case_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `rc_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `rm_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `vat` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(16,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `volume` decimal(16,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `is_abnormal` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `estimate_profit` decimal(16,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `business_man_id` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `business_man` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `net_amount_summary` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL,
  `domestic_amount` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL,
  `secret_key` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
  `secretKey` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_refund_include_tax` decimal(16,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `total_refund_money` decimal(16,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `total_refund_tax` decimal(16,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `total_return_goods` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `key_order_no` (`order_no`),
  KEY `idx_order_company_id` (`company_id`,`created_time`),
  KEY `IDX_RM_TIME` (`rm_time`),
  KEY `IDX_IS_ABNORMAL` (`is_abnormal`),
  KEY `cerp_oms_order_company_id_index` (`company_id`),
  KEY `idx_order_company_status_deleted` (`company_id`,`is_deleted`,`system_status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='system order table'
```

```
explain select *
from cerp_oms_order
         inner join (select id
                     from cerp_oms_order
                     where source_type = 43
                     order by created_time) as tmp using (id);
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | cerp_oms_order | null | ALL | PRIMARY | null | null | null | 60787 | 10 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | cerp_oms_order | null | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | cerp_oms_1.cerp_oms_order.id | 1 | 100 | null |

using inner join `execution: 7 ms, fetching: 109 ms`

**VS**

```
explain
select *
from cerp_oms_order
where source_type = 43
order by created_time;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | cerp_oms_order | null | ALL | null | null | null | null | 60787 | 10 | Using where; Using filesort |

using simple where clause `execution: 80 ms, fetching: 138 ms`

**I don't understand why use `inner join` can speed up my sql?**

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename;` and `explain select ...` for both queries

Comment: Also note that the second query has no order by...the order by in the subquery doesn't necessarily have any effect on the output

Comment: Ok, both queries just read the entire table using the clustered index.  The faster query just returns the rows, which happen to be in id order.  The slower query sorts by creation time, making it slower

Answer (score 0):

If you had

```
INDEX(source_type, created_time)
```

both formulations would run faster.  And, I think, the second would be faster.

As for "why".  Look at what the second does:

1. Scan the entire table ("table scan") looking for rows with `source_type = 43`.
2. For each matching row, gather all the columns (`*`) from the row, into a temp table.
3. Sort that temp table.  Note that this is bulkier than with the subquery that hauls around *only* `id`.
4. Deliver the results.

With the `INDEX` I suggest:

1. Look in the index's B+Tree for all 'rows' with `source_type = 43`.
2. Since those rows are sorted by `created_time`, not "sort" pass will be needed now or later.
3. Each of those index rows will contain `id`.  (That's the way InnoDB gets to the rest of the columns), so
4. Look up the desired rows in the data's B+Tree and pull out all (`*`) the columns.
5. Deliver them.

Note that the `JOIN` version works essentially the same, but, technically speaking, the `ORDER BY` may get lost.  If it does get lost, you would need to add a second `ORDER BY`, thereby forcing a sort.

(Unrelated)  Your "KEY `cerp_oms_order_company_id_index` (`company_id`)," can be dropped since there are two other indexes *starting with* `company_id`.

More on optimizing indexes: [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)